# Adding Items to Collection using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am having truble accessing ObservableCollection (which is my ItemsSource) from command attached to each of the items.

I am trying make two list, one with all the objects and the second one with objects picked by user.

Here is my view model.

```
class ViewModel : VMBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Card> _cardsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Card> CardsCollection
    {
        get { return _cardsCollection; }
        set { _cardsCollection = value; }
    }

    static private ObservableCollection<Card> _pickedCards;
    static public ObservableCollection<Card> PickedCards
    {
        get { return _pickedCards; }
        set { _pickedCards = value;
              NotifyPropertyChanged("PickedCards");
            }
    }
}
class Card : VMBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Card(string name, int cost, CardType type, CardRarity rarity)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.BackgroundImage = String.Format("/Images/Cards/{0}.png", name);

        this.PickCardCommand = new MvvmCommand();
        this.PickCardCommand.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true;
        this.PickCardCommand.ExecuteFunction = PickCard;
    }
    public MvvmCommand PickCardCommand { get; set; }
    public void PickCard(object parameter)
    {
        PickedCards.Add(currentCard); 
        //Above Does not work, not accessible
        CreateDeckModel.PickedCards.Add(currentCard);
        //Above does work but only if Collection is static
        //but if collection is static I am unable to call NotifyPropertyChanged()
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML file with binding

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CardsCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                  <Button Height="258" Width="180" Content="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                          Command="{Binding PickCardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                      <Button.Template>
                          <ControlTemplate>
                              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                  <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Height="258" Width="180">
                                      <Border.Background>
                                          <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImage}" />
                                      </Border.Background>
                                   </Border>
                              </StackPanel>
                          </ControlTemplate>
                       </Button.Template>
                   </Button>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </GridView.ItemTemplate>
   </GridView>
```

Here is my MvvmCommand Class

```
class MvvmCommand : ICommand
{
    public Predicate<object> CanExecuteFunc { get; set; }
    public Action<object> ExecuteFunction { get; set; }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteFunction(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to access ItemsSource from Item or DataContext alternatively make command accessible for ViewModel Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point the Command to your ViewModel class by changing the button in your xaml file to the following:

```
<Button Height="258" Width="180" Content="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Command="{Binding DataContext.PickCardCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type vw:ViewClass}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

In the RelativeSource binding you will need to change the following:

**vw** is the namespace for your View, this will have to be declared with the other namespaces in your xaml file.

**ViewClass** is the name of your class.

Then you obviously need to move the Command over to the ViewModel class from your Card class.

**Windows Phone**

```
<GridView x:Name="myGridView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CardsCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                  <Button Height="258" Width="180" Content="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                          Command="{Binding ElementName=myGridView,
                   Path=DataContext.PickCardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                      <Button.Template>
                          <ControlTemplate>
                              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                  <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" Height="258" Width="180">
                                      <Border.Background>
                                          <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImage}" />
                                      </Border.Background>
                                   </Border>
                              </StackPanel>
                          </ControlTemplate>
                       </Button.Template>
                   </Button>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </GridView.ItemTemplate>
   </GridView>
```

You will see that I have now named the GridView and then used the name of the GridView in the binding as the ElementName. I believe this should work.

Comment: I think his command binding is correct he needs a way to access the parent collection of the items.

Comment: If he wants to modify a collection on the parent ViewModel then it would be much cleaner to declare the Command on the ViewModel and modify the collection there.

Comment: Unfortunately FindAncestor is not accessible in Windows Phone.

Comment: @user2847238 I have updated my answer with a Windows Phone section.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the `Add` method of `PickedCards` to the `Card` when you create it:

```
class Card : VMBase
{
    private readonly Action<Card> _addCard;

    public Card(..., Action<Card> addCard)
    {
        ...
        _addCard = addCard;

        this.PickCardCommand = new MvvmCommand();
        this.PickCardCommand.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true;
        this.PickCardCommand.ExecuteFunction = PickCard;
    }

    public MvvmCommand PickCardCommand { get; set; }

    public void PickCard(object parameter)
    {
        _addCard(this);
    }
}
```

Then when you create the card:

```
var card = new Card(..., ..., ..., ..., PickedCards.Add)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bind your collection to the Command parameter. Command parameter is currently bound to Item DataSource and not collection

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

Instead use RelativeBinding and bind to itemSource of grid

Comment: let me know if you need help in relative binding

Comment: Would be nice if You could help me with it.